# Modified XML file not saving java

Tags: java, xml, servlets, dom, xml-parsing

I am making a web application, and I need to make a log. I am storing this log as an xml file.

These are my paths:

**log.xml -> org.codealizer.quizme.resources**

**Servlet -> org.codealizer.quizme.servlets**

When my application runs, it gives me a  success result, but the xml file is not modified.

This is my code to modify the xml file:

```
private void createLog(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, PrintWriter out) {
    String ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
    int port = request.getRemotePort();
    String clientInformation = request.getHeader("user-agent");

    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(getClass().getResourceAsStream(
                "/org/codealizer/quizme/resources/log.xml"));

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        Node log = doc.getFirstChild();

        Element item = doc.createElement("item");

        Element time = doc.createElement("time");
        time.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("" + System.currentTimeMillis()));
        item.appendChild(time);

        Element access = doc.createElement("access");
        access.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(getClass().getName()));
        item.appendChild(access);

        Element address = doc.createElement("address");
        address.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(ipAddress + ":" + port));
        item.appendChild(address);

        Element client = doc.createElement("client");
        client.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(clientInformation));
        item.appendChild(client);

        log.appendChild(item);

        // Update
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory
                .newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(getClass().getResource(
                "/org/codealizer/quizme/resources/log.xml").getFile());

        // Output to console for testing
        // StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);

        transformer.transform(source, result);

    } catch (SAXException | IOException | ParserConfigurationException
            | TransformerException e) {
        out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

This is my current log.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<log></log>
```

Could someone please help me fix this issue? Thx a lot :)

Comment: I take it that there is no exception thrown?
In which context are you executing this code? (IDE, jar file?)
Not sure but I would say the problem comes from `getClass().getResource("/org/codealizer/quizme/resources/log.xml")`. Can you try to replace this with `new File(" ...path.../org/codealizer/quizme/resources/log.xml")`? The thing is this won't work out of your IDE (because you can't modify a file among your sources in a jar file).

Comment: I tried putting the xml file in the WEB-INF folder of my webapp and I accessed it using the path of C:/..., however its still not working